# Scala scala.js cannot find module js script in sbt build

Tags: javascript, scala, sbt, scala.js

I'm trying to import a JS Script `script.js` into a scala program `App.scala` and use its methods `add` and `divide`.

However on running the program, I keep getting the error, `Cannot find module 'resources/script.js'`.

The sbt main folder structure looks something like below:

../main

```
  /resources

  -script.js

  /scala/example

  -App.scala
```

Could you please help me spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

App.scala:

```scala
package example
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation._

@js.native
@JSImport("resources/script.js","MyType")
class MyType(var x:Double, var y:Double) extends js.Object {
    ...
}

object Hello extends App {
    work() 

    @JSExport
    def work(): Unit = {
    ...
    }
}
```

script.js:

```js
class MyType {
    constructor(x, y) {
      ...
    }

    add(z){
      ...
    }

    divide(z){
       ...
    }
};

module.exports = {MyType};
```

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.10.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scalajs-crossproject" % "1.0.0")
```

build.sbt:

```
import Dependencies._
import org.scalajs.linker.interface.ModuleInitializer

ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.8"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "add",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

// ECMAScript
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.ESModule) }
// CommonJS
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.CommonJSModule) }

// See https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Sonatype.html for instructions on how to publish to Sonatype.
```

Comment: "However on running the program" How do you run the program? From sbt? From a web page?

Comment: sbt run (command terminal)